# Unable to resize the partition because the disk was locked in Ubuntu 18.X

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04, gparted

I tried to resize the partition using GParted, and it didnt work because it's being used by system.

[image]

Someone said that i need to do the GParted in a live CD, so i made a Ubuntu Installer into a USB using **rufus**. I also changed the boot priority in BIOS to boot the USB stick first. But i am unable to enter the live CD installer. It just keep appear the grub menu which show which OS should i use, Ubuntu or Windows.

How could i resize the ubuntu partition in proper way ?

EDIT

I got this when try to enter UEFI: USB using teh ESC key.

[image]

EDIT 2

I tried the duplicated question's answer but it turns to be like this

[image]

Comment: Which system are you using?

Comment: @Kulfy what do you mean "System" ? OS ?

Comment: My apologize, i am not quite understand with that question..., Which system ? My problem is on my laptop. @Kulfy

Comment: Oh sorry, I am using ASUS X450C @Kulfy

Comment: Try hitting Esc key as soon the laptop starts. This might provide you a menu. See which key is supposed to open Boot device options.

Comment: okay, i will try

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to go to boot menu in your laptop. From there you can easily boot through your USB stick.

To enter into boot menu in Asus laptop, you have to press 'escape' key 5-10 times as you turn your laptop on.